# How to proceed with this multi-variable recurrence?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I am trying to solve the following recurrence:

$$a_{0,j}=a_{i,0}=1$$
$$a_{i+1,j+1}=a_{i+1,j}+a_{i,j+1}+a_{i,j}$$

Following the method outlined in *Concrete Mathematics,* I ended up with the following closed form:

$$\sum_{0\le i,j}x^iy^ja_{i,j}={1\over1-x-y-xy}.$$

However, I was not able to find terms for the coefficients.  I see two ways to proceed; one leads to an ugly trinomial that doesn't seem to yield anything nice:

$${1\over1-(x+y+xy)}=\sum_{0\le n}(x+y+xy)^n$$

while the other idea works out somewhat nicer:

$${1\over2-(x+1)(y+1)}=\sum_{0\le n}{1\over2^{n+1}}(x+1)^n(y+1)^n.$$

giving me the following infinite sum as an almost-closed form:

$$a_{i,j}=\sum_{0\le n}{1\over2^{n+1}}{n\choose i}{n\choose j}$$

where I have no idea to eliminate the infinite sum.

Proceeding by first solving for $x^i$ and then solving the resulting closed form for $y^j$, we first get

$$\sum_{0\le j}y^ja_{i,j}={(1+y)^n\over(1-y)^{n+1}}$$

and then, extracting the coefficients for $y^j$:

$$a_{i,j}=\sum_{k=0}^j{k+i\choose i}{i\choose j-k}$$

which too looks nice, but I don't quite see a way to get rid of the sum.

What's the best way to proceed here? Just a hint would be nice so I can work out the details myself.

Comment: From the first closed form, I would try to calculate the (first, second, third...) derivative wrt x, and then set $x$ to $0$. Might help, not sure.

Comment: @5xum I got a bit further.  Any idea how to progress from here?  I'm not sure if derivatives help, but I can give it a try.

Comment: One way to proceed in finding the coefficient of $x^m y^n$ is to first regard $y$ as a constant and find the coefficient of $x^m$, which will be a function of $y$.  Then find the coefficient of $y^n$ in that function.

Comment: @awkward I tried that, I get $a_{i,j}=\sum_{k=0}^j{i+k\choose i}{i\choose j-k}$ which is a bit nicer, but I have no idea how to get rid of that sum.

Comment: You have a function of $i$ and $j$ which you can compute, so that looks like an answer.  Maybe it can be simplified, or maybe not.  The answers to combinatorics problems aren't always simple.

Comment: @awkward I do expect there to be a closed form; I'm not really happy with just this sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Hint:** The numbers $a_{i,j}$ form a sequence 
>   \begin{align*}
> \{1\},\{1,1\},\{1,3,1\},\{1,5,5,1\},\{1,7,13,7,1\},\{1,9,25,25,9,1\},\ldots
> \end{align*}
>   which is stored as *[A008288](https://oeis.org/A008288)* in OEIS and called the *Square array of Delannoy  numbers $D(n,k)$ read by antidiagonals*.
>
> We find there
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n \geq 0, k\geq 0} D(n, k)x^ny^k = \frac{1}{1-x-y-xy}
> \end{align*}
>
> We also find the identities
>   \begin{align*}
> D(n, k) = \sum_{d} \binom{k}{d}\binom{n+k-d}{k} = \sum_{d} 2^d\binom{n}{d}\binom{k}{d}
> \end{align*}
>   but regrettably  there is no closed formula given, which strongly indicates that no one is available.