# Proving/Deriving relation between determinant and order.

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations, determinant

$${ a }_{ 1,n }={ a }_{ n,1 }=1\quad \forall \quad n $$   $${ a }_{ i+1,j+1 }={ a }_{ i,j }+{ a }_{ i,j+1 }+{ a }_{ i+1,j }$$

Let $A$ be the matrix ($k$ order) made by using ${ a }_{ i,j }$ as element in $i$th row and $j$th column,in other words $A={ \left[ { a }_{ i,j } \right]  }_{ k*k }$

Find the determinant of matrix $A$ in terms of $k$

---

For example, for $k=4$, $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\ 1 & 5 & 13 & 25 \\ 1 & 7 & 25 & 63 \end{bmatrix}$

I calculated some determinants and found that the determinants form a series
$2^0,2^1,2^3,2^6,{2}^{10}...$

Looking at the patterns the determinant should be ${2}^{(k-1)(k)/2}$ but i have no way of doing that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [How to proceed with this multi-variable recurrence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3074411/how-to-proceed-with-this-multi-variable-recurrence) and [A008288](https://oeis.org/A008288) in the OEIS, the $a_{ij}$ are  the [Delannoy numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number) (only indexed differently), and we have the formula
$$
a_{i,j} = D(i-1, j-1) = \sum_{d=1}^k \underbrace{\binom{i-1}{d-1}}_{b_{i,d}}
\cdot 2^d \cdot \underbrace{\binom{j-1}{d-1}}_{b_{j, d}} \, .
$$
It follows that $A = B D B^T$ where $B$ is a lower triangular matrix (of binomial coefficients) with $(1, \ldots, 1)$ on the diagonal, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with $(2^0,\ldots,2^{k-1})$ on the diagonal. Therefore 
$$
 \det(A) =  \det(D) = 2^0 \cdot 2^1 \cdots 2^{k-1} = 2^{(k-1)k/2}
$$
as you conjectured.

As an example, for $k=4$:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 &  2 &  1 & 0 \\ 1 &  3&  3 &  1 \end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix} 2^0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2^1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &  0 &  2^2 & 0 \\ 0 &  0&  0 &  2^3 \end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's so cool that another question had the exact same recurrence relation.
Can i just ask how did you come up that $A$ will be a product of $B$ and $C$?

Comment: @ShauryamAkhoury: I found the other question [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7B%20a%20%7D_%7B%20i%2B1%2Cj%2B1%20%7D%3D%7B%20a%20%7D_%7B%20i%2Cj%20%7D%2B%7B%20a%20%7D_%7B%20i%2Cj%2B1%20%7D%2B%7B%20a%20%7D_%7B%20i%2B1%2Cj%20%7D%24%2C%20determinant&p=1). Then I noticed that the formula is of the form $a_{ij} = \sum b_{id} c_{dj}$, which is the formula for matrix multiplication. Finally both $B$ and $C$ are triangular matrices because of the binomial coefficients.